# Apache reverse proxy for slow connections

Tags: apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache 2.4.39 httpd acting as reverse proxy to docker containers running Apache 2.4.39 + PHP. In all the PHP applications I can't upload files with a "minimum size" (PHP upload limit is 600 MB). I've tested the upload of a 10 MB "file.avi" through Explorer and I've noted that the progress percentage on the browser is restarted a few times before the process is canceled without any errors on screen. It happens on other applications like Joomla, WordPress, etc.

Some facts:

1. When testing in my company, in which the link speed is around symetric 400 Mbp/s everything works fine.
2. When testing in home, with 15Mbps ADSL link, the problem happens.
3. When testing in home, bypassing the reverse proxy, uploading directly to the container's Apache, works fine too.

So the problem is on the Apache reverse proxy.

```
[Fri Aug 16 16:57:46.365452 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 15176:tid 139631072872192] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client ***.***.***.***:55884] AH02609: read request body failed to 127.0.0.1:9002 (127.0.0.1) from ***.***.***.*** (), referer: https://somewhere.com/ <br/>
[Fri Aug 16 16:57:46.365563 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 15176:tid 139631072872192] [client ***.***.***.***:55884] AH01097: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:9002 (127.0.0.1) from ***.***.***.*** (), referer: https://somewhere.com/
```

I've tried to set all TimeOut, connectiontimeout and timeout settings to big values, like 600 seconds, but no success. Please help, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Upgraded from apache 2.4.39 to 2.4.41 solved.